# Explicit construction of entity type '' in query is not allowed

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I'm getting the following error

```
Explicit construction of entity type '...TableClassName' in query is not allowed.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Here's my code.

```
tgdd = new List<TableClassName>();
    context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
    var t = context.TableClassName.Where(...)
                                  .GroupBy(g => new { g.Date, g.UserID })
                                  .Select(g => new TableClassName
                                  {
                                        PK = 1,
                                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(g.Key),
                                        Counted = g.Sum(x => x.Counted),
                                        Time = g.Sum(x => x.Time),
                                        MaxHR = g.Max(x => x.MaxHR),
                                        PeakCal = g.Max(x => x.PeakCal),
                                        PowerIndex = (g.Sum(x => x.PowerIndex)),
                                        Target = g.Max(x => x.Target),
                                        RepTotal = g.Sum(x => x.RepTotal),
                                        Lifted = g.Sum(x => x.Lifted),
                                        UserID = Convert.ToInt64(g.Key)
                                   }).ToList();

                        foreach (TableClassName r in t)
                        {
                            tgdd.Add(r);
                        }
```

I have no syntax errors.  This is a web service.  I get the issue when calling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used anonymous types to solve this issue (removed the TableClassName after the key word "new").

Then I had another issue, iterating through the var, using my TableClassName (error due to the contents in var being anonymous).

I iterated through the var, using var, and then extracting the contents of each var one by one into my object, then adding the object to my list as originally intended.  Here's my code for that.

```
foreach (var v in t)
{
    TableClassName tgData = new TableClassName();
    tgData.PK = v.PK;
    tgData.Date = v.Date;
    tgData.Counted= v.Counted;
    tgData.Time = v.Time;
    tgData.MaxHR = v.MaxHR;
    tgData.PeakCal = v.PeakCal;
    tgData.PowerIndex = v.PowerIndex;
    tgData.Target = v.Target;
    tgData.RepTotal = v.RepTotal;
    tgData.Lifted = v.Lifted;
    tgData.UserID = v.UserID;
    tgdd.Add(tgData);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:

```
context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false; 
tgdd = context.TableClassName.Where(...) 
                             .GroupBy(g => new { g.Date, g.UserID })
                             .AsEnumerable() 
                             .Select(g => new TableClassName 
                             { 
                                   PK = 1, 
                                   Date = Convert.ToDateTime(g.Key), 
                                   Counted = g.Sum(x => x.Counted), 
                                   Time = g.Sum(x => x.Time), 
                                   MaxHR = g.Max(x => x.MaxHR), 
                                   PeakCal = g.Max(x => x.PeakCal), 
                                   PowerIndex = (g.Sum(x => x.PowerIndex)), 
                                   Target = g.Max(x => x.Target), 
                                   RepTotal = g.Sum(x => x.RepTotal), 
                                   Lifted = g.Sum(x => x.Lifted), 
                                   UserID = Convert.ToInt64(g.Key) 
                              }).ToList();
```

By calling AsEnumerable after the Group operation, we force the projection into the custom type on the client side rather than in the server where the serve donesn't know about your custom type. Also, by calling ToList on the query, you don't need to iterate over the results and add them to yet another list. Just assign the results of the first ToList directly to the object that you are returning.

Comment: You'd want to be very careful about how that is translated into SQL. Since you're now doing the aggregations in memory rather than DB, it's like to be turned into a call for `SELECT DISTINCT data, userID FROM TableName` followed by another call for each set of rows that match the result of that first call, which could mean replacing a single database call with thousands (I've had variations on that sneak past me more than once). See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11805099/400547 for an examination of this.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting out the "new TableClassName" part from the LINQ query.

You might want to check out this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/1ce25da3-44c6-407d-8395-4c146930004b/

"The usage pattern for entities is that they are created outside of queries and inserted into tables via the DataContext and then later retrieved via queries, never created by queries"

Comment: Any tips on how I can separate them?  I'm new to LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, if you create a new derived class without the [Table]-Attribute like this:

```
public class TableClassNameLocal : TableClassName
{
}
```

Then you can create an instance of "TableClassNameLocal" inside the select. Cast the new instance directly to "TableClassName" and it will work!

```
result = new List<TableClassName>();
context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
var t = context.TableClassName.Where(...)
                              .GroupBy(g => new { g.Date, g.UserID })
                              .Select(g => (TableClassName)new TableClassNameLocal
                              {
                                    PK = 1,
                                    Date = Convert.ToDateTime(g.Key),
                                    Counted = g.Sum(x => x.Counted),
                                    Time = g.Sum(x => x.Time),
                                    MaxHR = g.Max(x => x.MaxHR),
                                    PeakCal = g.Max(x => x.PeakCal),
                                    PowerIndex = (g.Sum(x => x.PowerIndex)),
                                    Target = g.Max(x => x.Target),
                                    RepTotal = g.Sum(x => x.RepTotal),
                                    Lifted = g.Sum(x => x.Lifted),
                                    UserID = Convert.ToInt64(g.Key)
                               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
  var roles = (from r in roleNames
                                    join rm in DataContext.FMC_RoleMaps on r equals rm.RoleName_old
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        dnnUser.UserID,
                                        rm.RoleID
                                    }
                                           );
                       foreach (var userRole in roles)
                       {
                           var newrole = new UserRole()
                                             {
                                                 RoleID = userRole.RoleID,
                                                 UserID = userRole.UserID
                                             };
                           DataContext.UserRoles.InsertOnSubmit(newrole);
                       }
```