# ASP.NET MVC2 Application showing Error in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq

Controller-

```
namespace TaskList.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
     //
     // GET: /Home/
     private TaskListDataContext  DB = new TaskListDataContext();

     //Task tasks = new Task();
     //Display a list of Tasks
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
        var tasks = from t in DB.Tasks
                    orderby t.EntryDate descending
                    select new TaskList.Models.Task()
                    {
                       Id = t.Id,
                       Task1 = t.Task1,
                       IsCompleted = t.IsCompleted,
                       EntryDate = t.EntryDate
                    };
        return View(tasks);
      }

      //Display a form for creating a new Task
      public ActionResult Create()
      {
         return View();
      }

      //Adding a new task to the database
      public ActionResult CreateNew(string tasktext)
      {
         //Add the new task to the database 
         Task newTask = new Task();
         newTask.Task1 = tasktext;
         newTask.IsCompleted = false;
         newTask.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;       
         DB.Tasks.InsertOnSubmit(newTask);
         DB.SubmitChanges();       
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }

      //Mark a task as complete
      public ActionResult Complete()
      {
         //Database Logic
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
   }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<TaskList.Models.Task>>"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>    
        <h1>My Tasks</h1>  
        <ul>
        <% foreach (TaskList.Models.Task task in ViewData.Model)
           {%>              
             <li>  
             <%  task.Task1.ToString(); %>
             </li>       
        <% } %>
        </ul>    
        <br /> <br />
        <a href='<%=Url.Action("Create")%>/filename'>Add my Tasks</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Model is made using Linq Class-

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Tasks")]
public partial class Task : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);       
   private int _Id;         
   private string _Task1;           
   private bool _IsCompleted;       
   private System.DateTime _EntryDate;      
}
```

When I am trying to run the Application it is showing me an error

> "Explicit construction of entity type 'TaskList.Models.Task' in query
>   is not allowed."

in the foreach loop of view.

Actually I am trying to create a C# veriosn of the Application built in VB over here.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/creating-a-tasklist-application-with-aspnet-mvc

Comment: I think this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/7362796/1239554

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787296/explicit-construction-of-entity-type-in-query-is-not-allowed

Comment: Thanks a lot but the error got rectified using har07's solution could you please help me with this "view is still not showing the Taskname strings as per the foreach loop I have added in the view"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you can't create mapped entity in query statement. You can either select existing entity :

```
var tasks = from t in DB.Tasks
            orderby t.EntryDate descending
            select t;
```

, or create list of new entities outside query :

```
var taskEntities = from t in DB.Tasks
                    orderby t.EntryDate descending
                    select t;
var tasks = new List<TaskList.Models.Task>();
foreach(var taskEntity in taskEntities)
{
    tasks.Add(new TaskList.Models.Task()
                {
                   Id = taskEntity.Id,
                   Task1 = taskEntity.Task1,
                   IsCompleted = taskEntity.IsCompleted,
                   EntryDate = taskEntity.EntryDate
                });
}
return View(tasks);
```

, depending on your requirement.

Comment: I tried adding in this way but it is showing compile time error saying the "The name 't' doesnot exist in the current context". I added this code to my Controller method Index().

Comment: Probably its because t is the part of Linq statment. Any other idea please?

Comment: my mistake, missed to edit that part. It has been updated now, you can try again with latest code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tha exception is gone. :) I have been banging my head on this since morning as I am new to this. But, I am still facing one issue in this the view is still not showing the Taskname strings as per the foreach loop I have added in the view. Could you please help?

Comment: You're welcome. And don't forget to mark this answer accepted when you have chance to do so :)

Comment: About Taskname strings not showing, sounds like another problem. Consider to open new question, describe the problem clearly as I don't currently get it (for example, what is taskname I can't find it in your current code).

Comment: Ohh ok... I will add it as a new question in sometime. Hope you that as well and I have a chance to accept the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert to list like,

```
var tasks = (from t in DB.Tasks orderby t.EntryDate descending select new TaskList.Models.Task() { Id = t.Id, Task1 = t.Task1, IsCompleted = t.IsCompleted, EntryDate = t.EntryDate }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried using this statment and it is showing the same exception as it is showing in my code.

Comment: Any other Suggestions please?